# Conditional emoji on terminal success and failure

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

I am using a Mac and I want to be able to show emoji X for every successful command that I type in and emoji Y for every command that results in failure.

Comment: Which shell are you using? This is facile to achieve in zsh.

Comment: bash, whatever is standard on mac.

Comment: While technically OSX is based on Linux, there's an active Mac-specific SE site and this question is much more appropriate there. You'd get better answers as well.

Comment: @Bagalaw I disagree. This is a purely bash question, and IMO appropriate for U/L.

Comment: @eugenekgn There are [numerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470018/set-last-command-exit-code-to-bash-prompt) [similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23515/display-non-zero-return-status-in-ps1/193344) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/bash-display-exit-status-in-prompt) on this site. Have a look and see if you can work it out from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash has some variables that let you control the prompt:

- `PROMPT_COMMAND`
- `PS1`
- `PS2`
- `PS3`
- `PS4`

In this specific scenario, only `PROMPT_COMMAND` (code executed before printing the primary prompt) and `PS1` (the primary prompt) are helpful.

And the variable `?` let you know the exit status of the last command executed. For example:

```
command

if [[ "${?}" == '0' ]]; then
  echo 'OK'
else
  echo 'ERROR'
fi
```

So you just need to take advantage of these handy features:

```
# Using PROMPT_COMMAND
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "${?}" == "0" ]]; then printf "[OK]"; else printf "[ERROR]"; fi'

# Using PS1
PS1='$(if [[ "${?}" == "0" ]]; then printf "[OK]"; else printf "[ERROR]"; fi)\$ '
```

Both ways would print something like this (assuming your initial prompt is `$`):

```
[OK]$ false
[ERROR]$ true
[OK]$
```

Just replace `[OK]` and `[ERROR]` with your desired emojis.

You can read the [Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) section of Bash manual to learn more about this topic.

Comment: Most people just say ``"$?"``.  I see no reason to include the `{` and the `}`; do you have one?

Comment: @G-Man It's just my personal preference. Neither the braces nor the quotes around `${?}` are really needed in that case AFAIK.

Comment: Well, *quoting* shell variables is always recommended; see [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), including [Steven Penny's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#280935).   [My answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525 "${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does ...") to another question is also relevant.

Comment: @G-Man Sorry, I didn't express myself correctly. What I meant is that there's no need to quote the `${?}` in `[[ "${?}" == "0" ]]` because word splitting doesn't affect such variable _in that specific case_. I quoted it anyway because, as Stéphane Chazelas said in the question you linked, "omitting quotes [...] can send a wrong message to beginners: that it may be all right not to quote variables". For the record, [I've also made an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440559/243481) about some subtleties of word splitting.